# why are php extended class properties not updated

Tags: php, class, methods, extend

I am attempting the extend DateTime as follows:

```
class testdate extends DateTime {
public $sqldate;

public function __construct($time)
{
    parent::__construct($time);
    //?? parent::modify();

    $this->sqldate = $this->format ("Y-m-d"); 
}

}
echo "<pre>";

$td = new testdate("2020-08-23");
echo "       Today's Date: ".$td->format ("m/d/Y").br;
echo "   Today's SQL Date: ".$td->sqldate.br.br;
$td->modify ("+24 hour");
echo "    Tomorrow;s Date: ".$td->format ("m/d/Y").br;    // 1 day added correctly
echo " Tomorrow Formatted: ".$td->format ("Y-m-d").br;
echo "  Tomorrow Sql Date: ".$td->sqldate.br.br;          //not updated
print_r ($td);
```

As you can see in the print_r statement, the date is updated but the sqldate is not.

What must I do to make certain that the properties of the extended class are updated?

Comment: You didn't include the result of `print_r`.  And it would help to show the exact outut of those echos.

Comment: `$this->sqldate` is not updated when `$td->modify()` is called.
You need to override the `modify()` method too.

Comment: Or just have `sqldate` be a method instead, as opposed to a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already commented the actual issue is that you only set the `sqldate` property you defined inside the constructor, so once when instanciating the object. You nowhere implemented an update to that property.

It would be possible to extend the derived class further, so that the `sqldate` property gets updated with every modification, but that is cumbersome and error prone. Reason is that the property keeps redundant information which then needs to be synchronized.

It is much more elegant to use a formatting method instead of a synchronized porperty for such situations:

```
<?php
define("br", "\n");

class testdate extends DateTime {
  public function getSqlDate() {
    return $this->format("Y.m.d");
  }
}

$td = new testdate("2020-08-23");
echo "       Today's Date: ".$td->format ("m/d/Y").br;
echo "   Today's SQL Date: ".$td->getSqlDate().br.br;
$td->modify ("+24 hour");
echo "    Tomorrow's Date: ".$td->format ("m/d/Y").br;
echo " Tomorrow Formatted: ".$td->format ("Y-m-d").br;
echo "  Tomorrow Sql Date: ".$td->getSqlDate().br.br;
```

The obvious output of that is:

```
       Today's Date: 08/23/2020
   Today's SQL Date: 2020.08.23

    Tomorrow's Date: 08/24/2020
 Tomorrow Formatted: 2020-08-24
  Tomorrow Sql Date: 2020.08.24
```